# while navigating to registration page first time, the optional parameter null error

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this object like below in dart,

```
{ name: , lastname: , phone: , email: }
```

and I log it like this,

```
class RegistrationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  //create a variable to get the data from the first page then register.
  final info;
  const RegistrationPage({this.info,Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RegistrationPage> createState() => _RegistrationPage();
}


class _RegistrationPage extends State<RegistrationPage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    logUserInfo();
  }

  void logUserInfo() {
    var userFilling = widget.info;
    log("$userFilling");
  }
```

After filling registration page, user has to fill a couple more pages before he/she can register, but he/she can also go back(navigate back) in the page.
So the thing is, if I navigate back to the registration, I want to have `widget.info` of the user something like this, and fill the text fields like before to allow the user for edits. So this optional argument is if user decides to navigate back and edit while registering.

```
{ name: "firstname", lastname: "lastname" , phone: +99999, email: "email@email.com"}
```

if a user is going to the page for the first time, the optional object can empty like above.

About the error I get, if  i just try to use the `.text` attribute of the controller on a string it works, yet if I try to use something like below

```
myController.text = (widget.info['email'] != null)?widget.info['email']:"",;
```

I get the error,

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null. Tried calling []("email")
```

How can I leave the `.text` empty if the object from the parameter is empty, or if not just fill it with the text of it... yet if i try to get the value from the object, I get the null error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer that you put `final Map<String, dynamic>? info` rather than just `final info`.
then I want you to add this code below your state.

```
 if(info != null) {
  controller.text = widget.info["email"]
}
```

Something like this, and in else condition you can just give them their default value.
Hope this works. ^^

Comment: thank you, what if for example, ```widget.info["name"]``` is filled, but ```widget.info["email"]``` is null, what to do then, because email is an optional field

Comment: ok, it works like this perfectly! thanks for the answer to the issue!

Comment: I see, then you should consider using the syntax that you used in your question, `myController.text = (widget.info['email'] != null)?widget.info['email']:"",;``This way, you are null safe now.